# Replying with "neither" in passive for active sentence

Tags: passive-voice, active-voice, neither-nor

For example: `They don't allow you to enter the room`. How to say that they don't allow me to enter too? What is the shortest way to say it? Is it possible to use `neither` in such situation? `Neither do me`?
Is it possible to replay on sentence in an active voice with a passive sentence?

Comment: **allow** takes an infinitival complement:  *allow {someone} **to enter***

Comment: Are you writing this or saying this. It makes a world of difference.

Comment: I am saying it. For writing, I think it is better to write long version because if someone gets you wrong you wouldn't have a chance to explain what did you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three possible practical responses in normal conversation, but only two of them are, technically (in a formal sense), grammatical:

> Me either.
>   Nor me.

First of all, look at the initial statement:

> They didn't allow me to enter the room.

There are a couple of long replies that could be made to this:

> They didn't allow me to enter the room either.
>   Nor did they allow me to enter the room.

When you use a shorter version of a sentence to stand for it's longer version, it's called an *elliptical* sentence. In other words, pieces of the sentence have been removed, leaving just enough components so that it is still understood.

With the example answers, the elliptical sentences are:

> (they didn't allow) **Me** to enter the room **either**.
>   **Nor** did they allow **me** to enter the room.

---

**Note 1**: In casual conversation, some people do still respond to this with **me neither**, but the problem, in terms of grammar, is that—in this specific example—if it's an elliptical sentence, then it could only come from an ungrammatical longer sentence:

> They didn't allow **me** to enter the room **neither**.

Therefore, **me neither** is (in a purely formal sense) ungrammatical.

However, having said that, such a response is commonly given in informal speech—and it would be understood by anybody who heard it.

---

**Note 2**: In the UK, **me either** is rarely used. Instead, at least in informal speech, it's normally **me neither**.

Answer (score -1):

If I say to you:

> They wouldn't let me in the room.

you can reply

> Me neither.

or

> Nor me.

**Me neither** is conversational. **Nor me** would sound a little formal to most speakers of American English.

You could also say

> They wouldn't let me in either.

But with **either** most native speakers in their reply would probably repeat some or all of the first speaker's statement, echoing the negative, **wouldn't**. A good many however would simply say

> Me either.

Comment: Context is all, obviously, but if the first statement had been *John wouldn't let Jane in the room,* we might reasonably understand the response *Me neither/Nor me* as meaning EITHER *John wouldn't let me in either* OR *I wouldn't let Jane in either.* And since OP hasn't given us the full context for his example, even that could be understood to mean ***I** won't let **you** in either.*

Comment: When the meaning of the reply is *I wouldn't let you in either*, I think **I wouldn't either** is far more likely than **me neither**, since **me neither** would probably be understood the other way around:  *They wouldn't let me in either*.

Comment: I can't really see that the ***either / neither, or / nor*** choices themselves particularly push toward one interpretation or the other. I think what's actually going on is that *by default* we assume the referent of ***nor me, me neither*** to be the most recently mentioned *(credible)* NP - so if that's *not* what's intended, we might explicitly repeat more elements from the preceding utterance to disambiguate. But if I consider *John doesn't like Jane* and possible responses #1 *Nor me* and #2 *Me neither*, I'm slightly inclined to prefer #1 for the sense *John doesn't like me either*.

Comment: Please don't reply *me neither*. I know people do say it, but, idiomatic usage aside, it's ungrammatical. It should be *me either* (as a shortened version of *they wouldn't let me in the room either*). Granted that adds ambiguity (*I wouldn't let you in the room either*) but at least it's grammatical. And I suspect if anybody actually meant the latter, they would use the full sentence (or *neither would I*)—or it would be clear in context.

Comment: @Jason Bassford: Your advice is misguided.  If it is idiomatic, it is grammatical.

Comment: Idiomatic: "peculiar to a particular group, individual, or style." Grammatical: "conforming to the rules of grammar · a grammatical sentence." It's quite idiomatic for people to say *I don't know nothin'* even though that's not the grammatical way of saying *I don't know anything*.

Comment: **idiomatic**: "Using, containing, or denoting expressions that are natural to a native speaker." *He spoke fluent, idiomatic English* (Oxford, https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/idiomatic)

Comment: *Me neither* is perfectly grammatical.  It's **less formal** than *Neither do I*, but it's important not to confuse formality with grammaticality.  *Me either* is also grammatical for many speakers, but that depends on dialect, so I usually recommend *me neither* to learners as a safer alternative.